# Proving the Heisenberg Group of modulo $p$ is isomorphic to $D_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Prove the Heisenberg Group of modulo $p$ is isomorphic to $D_8$.

I'm having trouble specifically figuring out the way $D_8$ can be related to the unipotent upper triangle matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$ to prove isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, presumably you need to prove that the Heisenberg group modulo **two** is isomorphic to $D_8$, because otherwise you have a group of order $p^3\neq 8$, and $D_8$ of course has order $8$. So let's assume you mean $p=2$.

Next, don't think about what the elements look like, but about how they behave. In $D_8$, you have an element of order $4$, $r$, and an element of order $2$, $s$, and $sr=r^3s$ ($r$ is the rotation and $s$ is the reflection, if you think of $D_8$ as the rigid motions of a square).

What about the group of matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & c\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),\qquad a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_2\text{?}$$
Presumably, you've played with the Heisenberg group, so you know that
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & c\\
0 & 1 & b
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x & z\\
0 & 1 & y\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a+x & c+z+ay\\
0 & 1 & b+y\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
Is there an element $\mathbf{x}$ of order $4$ that can be a candidate of corresponding to $r$? Is there an element $\mathbf{y}$ of order $2$ that satisfies $\mathbf{yx} = \mathbf{x}^3\mathbf{y}$? Can you make that into an isomorphism?

(Alternatively, if you've classified the groups of order $8$, you know there are three abelian groups, namely $C_8$, $C_4\times C_2$, and $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$; and two nonabelian groups, namely $D_8$ and $Q_8$, so you would just need to check to see whether the Heisenberg group is abelian or not, and whether it can be $Q_8$ or not.)

Comment: OP: If you're interested in the alternative method Arturo mentions, one way to distinguish between $D_8$ and $Q_8$ is to use that all of the subgroups of the latter of order $4$ are cyclic, whereas that is not the case for $D_8$.

Comment: If I was to just find the appropriate matrices corresponding to x and y as described above, would that be enough to prove isomorphism? Or do I need to go the further step of defining a bijective function.  If so, it would be $\varphi: U_3(\mathbb{F}_2) \rightarrow D_8$ but then what is the next step?

Comment: @Sam: It depends on what you know. If you know von Dyck’s Theorem, then finding the appropriate matrices and showing that they satisfy the appropriate relations ensures the existence of a function. Otherwise, You should define the function and show it works.